# Delete annoying hashtags from a string using javascript regax

Tags: javascript

How to delete the whole line if it all is hashtags using JavaScript regex, for example:

```
text #string
#hashtag1 #hashtag2 #hashtag3
```

it will be:

```
text #string
```

Thank you for all answers

Comment: to delete or to replace with `'empty'` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest delete it

Comment: ('#hashtag #hashtag #hashtag').replace(/#hashtag/g,'').trim()

Comment: @naortor NO I want the solution using regex. Thank you.

Comment: @anmml then add regex to the tags. That aside, you don't necessarely need a regex for such. Also, did you try something?

Comment: @briosheje I want to use it for different hashtags, so using regex is necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
text.replace(/^(\s*#\w+\s*)+$/gm, "")
```

Notice `m` flag there, it means 'multiline'.

Comment: Works perfect . Thank you .

Comment: to support the other languages (not English) should use this `/^(\s*#([^\x00-\x7F]|\w)+\s*)+$/gm`

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will help

```
string.replace(/\#\S+/g,'');
```

UPD: I got you. try this:

```
string.replace(/(\n|^)(\#\S+\s+|\#\S+)+(\n|$)/g,'');
```

Comment: it delete all hashtags. I just want it to delete the line if it all is hashtags.

Comment: @anmml Please, take a look at new version

Comment: like this: `#a #b \n #c #d` it just delete `#a #b`

Comment: @anmml I've edited it. Have you tried latest version?